# EF4 MVC3 model state validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Using this model:

```
public class Cases
    {
    //case data model for call center
    //implement lists for all related child tables too

    [Key]
    public int CasesID { get; set; }

    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer is Required")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }  //get user name from the aspnet membership

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Case Category is Required")]
    public int CaseCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Technician is Required")]
    public int TechnicianID { get; set; }
    public virtual Technician Technicians { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engine Model is Required")]
    public int EngineModelID { get; set; }
    public virtual EngineModel EngineModel { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string BMSWorkorder { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is Required")]
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string OpenedBy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Opened Date is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? OpenedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClosedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Caller First Name is Required")]
    public string CallerFirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Caller Last Name is Required")]
    public string CallerLastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AdditionalContact { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Qualified is Required")]
    public string Qualified { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ESN is Required")]
    public string ESN { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mileage is Required")]
    public string Mileage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateInService { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ESTR { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EDS is Required")]
    public string EDS { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetSerialNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetModelNumber { get; set; }

    //child Case Notes records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseNotes> CaseNotes { get; set; }

    //child case attachment records
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    //child case complaint records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseComplaint> CaseComplaint { get; set; }

    //tracking fields
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

I am wondering why even though only some of the properties are marked required, the modelstate does not get set valid unless all properties have values when saving.

Am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT***

Here are my razor elements for the dropdownlist fields in question:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Qualified", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qualified)

@Html.DropDownList("EngineModelID", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EngineModelID)

@Html.DropDownList("CaseCategoryID", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaseCategoryID)
```

Comment: Which properties in particular?

Comment: Some of those integer properties should probably be made nullable.

Comment: I noticed with some breakpoints that my validation annotations are not working on view fields that are dropdownlists. Any trick to those?

Comment: I added my view elements in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EngineModelID` and `CaseCategoryID` properties must be nullable integers on your view model if you want to allow empty values. Oooops, you are not using view models.

ASP.NET MVC automatically makes non-nullable types required. You could disable this explicitly in your `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

But if you want to do the things properly you should use view models.

The following is absolutely horrible:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CaseCategoryID", String.Empty)
```

I guess you have stuffed a `SelectList` in a `ViewBag.CaseCategoryID` so the `CaseCategoryID` does 2 things at the same time: it represents a list and a selected scalar value.

With view models you would use the strongly typed version of those helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CaseCategoryID, Model.CaseCategories)
```

where `CaseCategories` will be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property on your view model that the controller would populate.

Comment: Yeah, it is my intention to change this view over to using a view model, but I am still learning. It seems that most of the tutorials out there are teaching "horrible" practices...:)
I actually want the EngineModelID and CaseCategoryID to be required.

Comment: I guess is there anyway to get this validation working so I can get the view(s) live for my team while I change it over to a viewmodel?

Comment: Did you try setting `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` to false?